# Как хранить периодически обновляемый массив в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Мне необходимо хранить некоторый набор данных (массив из id нескольких постов и соответствующих им меток), обновляя его с определённой частотой. Обновление легко реализуется с помощью `wp_cron`. А вот с хранением тупик.
Поделитесь, пожалуйста, идеями о том, как в WP можно хранить подобные данные без привязки к определённой статье.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решила задачу сохранением массива как строки в таблице `wp_options`

```
update_option('my_array', json_encode($arr));
```

И последующим извлечением данных и конвертированием строки обратно в массив

```
$arr = get_option('my_array', 0);
if ($arr) $arr = json_decode($arr);
```

Comment: можно и таблицу в БД создать, 2 поля: ключ - значение, и писать туда.

Comment: @pepel_xD, чисто теоретически - да. Но вопрос в том, что делать, если через какое-то время понадобится сохранить ещё с десяток подобных массивов? Хотя можно, конечно, завести 3 поля: имя, ключ, значение.

Comment: ну та же проблема. Опции то все равно хранятся в БД. Соответственно запрос к базе все равно происходит. Только в этом случае еще необходимо строку конвертнуть в массив и его обработать.